# Syntax error in continuous assignment

Tags: verilog

Why is there a syntax error in the continuous assignment to the `out_money` signal?

```
module tb;
  reg clk, reset_b, start;
  wire [15:0] seed, q, random;
  wire        seed_pulse;
  reg [6:0] in_money ;
  reg [3:0] in_value1, in_value2, in_value3 ;
  reg [10:0] out_money;
     
  counter u1(.clk(clk), .reset_b(reset_b), .start(start), .cnt(seed), .seed_pulse(seed_pulse));
  lfsr u2(.clk(clk), .reset_b(reset_b), .seed_pulse(seed_pulse), .cnt(seed), .q(q));
  random u3 (.clk(clk), .reset_b(reset_b), .start(start), .q(q), .random(random));
     
  initial begin
    in_value1 = 4'd3;
    in_value2 = 4'd0;
    in_value3 = 4'd0;
  end
    
  wire [3:0] random1, random2, random3;
    
  assign random1 = random[11:8]%10;
  assign random2 = random[7:4]%10;
  assign random3 = random[3:0]%10;
  assign out_money = ((random1 == in_value1) && (random2 == in_value2) && (random3 == in_value3)) ? in_money * 10 ;
    
  initial clk = 0;

  always #5 clk = ~clk;

  initial begin
    reset_b = 0;
    #8 reset_b = 1;
  end
     
  initial begin
    start = 0;
    #38 start = 1;
    #100 start = 0;
    #50 $finish;
  end
     
  initial
    $monitor("time:%3d, start:%b, seed: %d, lfsr: %d, random: %d", $time, start, seed, q, random);
     
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and tell us exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simulators do not yield very descriptive error messages.  But, others sometimes do.  You can try to compile your code on multiple simulators available on the `edaplayground` site.

The Cadence simulator shows:

```
  assign out_money = ((random1 == in_value1) && (random2 == in_value2) && (random3 == in_value3)) ? in_money * 10 ;
                                                                                                                  |
xmvlog: *E,BADTNO : expecting a colon (':') in the conditional operator [4.1.13(IEEE)].
```

This informs you that the compiler thinks you are trying to  use the *conditional* operator, which has the general form:

```
(condition) ? expression1 : expression2;
```

You code has the "condition" and "expression1" components, but it is missing the colon and "expression2".

To get rid of the syntax error, add a "expression2".  For example:

```
  assign out_money = ((random1 == in_value1) && (random2 == in_value2) && (random3 == in_value3)) ? in_money * 10 : {10{1'b0}};
```